# JavaFX CSS type based selectors

Tags: css, javafx-2

I'm having difficultly understanding JavaFX CSS type selectors. I've had a good look at the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

If I want to customize the spacing of layout elements such as HBox and VBox using the -fx-spacing rule do I have to add a custom CSS class to them all manually before I can reference them??

```
hBox.getStyleClass().add("hbox")
vBox.getStyleClass().add("vbox")
```

There doesn't seem to be a type based selection like this:

```
hbox {
   -fx-spacing: 5
}
```

HBox and VBox are documented as "Style class: empty by default" I'm used to HTML where you can select by element type, e.g. div, button etc. I've got a lot of layouts and I don't want to have to go through them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with capital letters?

```
HBox {
  -fx-spacing:10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Whereabouts is that in the CSS reference?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html "JavaFX CSS also has some extensions to CSS in support of specific JavaFX features" if it answer you question, mark it as correct answer.